# How do I share entity objects between multiple endpoints in Google App Engine using appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, datastore

I have an entity to send a contactList to a java enpoint in Google App Engine:

```
@Entity
public class ContactList {

    private ArrayList<Contact> list;

    public ArrayList<Contact> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Contact> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

I have another endpoint that I would like to send the same entity to. When developing both Enpoints in Android Studio I have one class for the shared entity:

```
package.shared.entities.ContactList
```

But when generating the client libs, it generates two versions of the entity:

```
package.enpointA.model.ContactList
package.enpointB.model.ContactList
```

**How do I share entity objects between multiple endpoints of a Google App Engine java backend using appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a consequence of the generation service. It actually generates and archive for each endpoint. The gradle plugin merges those in to one archive but preserves all the package paths. I think a way around this is to manage your API as one endpoint and as multiple classes. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass

Comment: Thanks, I will go for a multi class api. That seems like better approach all together.